# How to get the last weeks data from an xts object

Tags: r, xts

E.g. if it is Dec 1st, I want it to pull out Wed, Nov 25th to Tue, Dec 1st, inclusive.

Note: `last()` is not the answer, as it gets the most recent data in the xts object, irrespective of the current day.

```
x = xts(1:10, as.Date("2015-12-01") - (30:21))
last(x,"1 week")  #2015-11-09, 2015-11-10
last(x,"7 days")  #2015-11-04 to 2015-11-10 inclusive.
```

In this example the function I'm looking for would return a blank object.

Ideally the solution would have all the power of the `last()` function, as being able to write `last(x,"2 hours")`, `last(x,"6 months")`, etc. is great.

Comment: Your condition doesn't match your example (no December).

Comment: @Pascal The example is to show why `last()` does not do what I need. (If the data goes up to the current day, then `last()` is fine.)

Comment: *"E.g. if it is Dec 1st, I want it to pull out Wed, Nov 25th to Tue, Dec 1st, inclusive."* Where are Dec 1st and so on in your example? It is what I wanted to point out.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be as simple as:

```
library(xts)

endDate = as.Date("2015-12-01")
startDate = endDate - 6

x = xts(1:100, as.Date("2015-12-30") - (1:100))
x[index(x) >= startDate & index(x) <= endDate,]

# [,1]
# 2015-11-25   35
# 2015-11-26   34
# 2015-11-27   33
# 2015-11-28   32
# 2015-11-29   31
# 2015-11-30   30
# 2015-12-01   29


x = xts(1:100, as.Date("2015-11-15") - (1:100))
x[index(x) >= startDate & index(x) <= endDate,] # Nothing there
```